# condition to check nan, ValueError: malformed node or string: nan

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

One of the columns in a pandas DataFrame is a dictionary. The column has a few empty cells and I'd like to check for them. I tried a few conditions that didn't work:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'id': ['7e9zsX7CM4', "y6t451h21"], 
                    'img_dict': ["defaultdict(< class 'list'>, {'7e9zsX7CM4': ['https://image_1.png','https://image_2.png']})", ""] 
                 })

img_dict = df['img_dict'][1]
img_dict = ast.literal_eval(img_dict)
    
#  conditions that didn't work 
if img_dict is None:

if img_dict == "": 

if img_dict == np.nan:

if not img_dict:


  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 99, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 98, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 75, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 66, in _convert_num
    _raise_malformed_node(node)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 63, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string: nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a nice method: pandas.DataFrame.dropna
It removes missing values. This is how I would apply it to your code

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'id': ['7e9zsX7CM4', "y6t451h21"], 
                    'img_dict': ["defaultdict(< class 'list'>, {'7e9zsX7CM4': ['https://image_1.png','https://image_2.png']})", ""] 
                 }).dropna()
```

Then to check for it:

```
if "" in df['img_dict']:
    pass
```

Comment: I'd like to retain them in the dataframe and apply a set of rules if the cell is empty / None. i.e a condition that check for empty value.

Comment: I am reference a particular cell, in this case `df['img_dict'][df.index[1]]`, and it doesn't evaluate the condition to be True.